# Selecting class in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

How can I select certain classes from a layer categorized by jenks with PyQGIS?

I have classified by 4 classes, but I only want to select the objects of class 1, 2, 4, so I need to have a method that automatically makes that selection cyclically in a large number of layers

```py
layer_name = 'sn_jose'
ramp_name = 'Reds'
value_field = 'ord_nov21'
num_classes = 4
classification_method = QgsClassificationJenks()

path_to_gpkg = ('e:/Users/alozanon/Desktop/07032022/baja_california.gpkg')
gpkg_baja_layer = path_to_gpkg + "|layername=sn_jose"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(gpkg_baja_layer, "sn_jose_"+value_field, "ogr")
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)


format = QgsRendererRangeLabelFormat()
format.setFormat("%1 - %2")
format.setPrecision(2)
format.setTrimTrailingZeroes(True)

default_style = QgsStyle().defaultStyle()
color_ramp = default_style.colorRamp(ramp_name)

renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer()
renderer.setClassAttribute(value_field)
renderer.setClassificationMethod(classification_method)
renderer.setLabelFormat(format)
renderer.updateClasses(vlayer, num_classes)
renderer.updateColorRamp(color_ramp)

vlayer.setRenderer(renderer)
vlayer.triggerRepaint()
```